# Devextreme dx-datagrid: Need to remove overlay screen while loading

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

I want to remove the overlay screen while loading the dx-datagrid.

[image: Need to remove overlay screen while dx-datagrid]

Reference: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the data grid load panel that appears while the datasource is loading you have to set the loadPanel property in DataGrid to enabled = false

I add the link reference: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/loadPanel/#enabled